# MySQL error: Subquery returns more than 1 row when trying to insert values

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have the following MySQL script. What I'm trying to do is:

- Get the 100 bestselling products
- Get their prices
- Calculate 20% off the price
- Then insert the **new** price into the specials table

This works well when I change the limit on my subqueries to **1**, but how can I do this for all 100 products in one script?

Here is the error I'm receiving: `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_special (product_id, customer_group_id, priority, price, date_start, date_end)
VALUES (

(SELECT op.product_id
FROM oc_order_product op 
LEFT JOIN oc_order o 
ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (op.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' 
AND p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = 0 
GROUP BY op.product_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 100),

"1","20",

(SELECT p.price * 0.8 AS "price" 
FROM oc_order_product op 
LEFT JOIN oc_order o 
ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (op.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' 
AND p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = 0 
GROUP BY op.product_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 100),

"2014-11-11","2030-01-01"
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's returning more than 1 row because the limit is 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `VALUES` when you want to insert all the results of a `SELECT`. Just use the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_special (product_id, customer_group_id, priority, price, date_start, date_end)
SELECT op.product_id, "1", "20", p.price * 0.8, "2014-11-11", "2030-01-01"
FROM oc_order_product op 
LEFT JOIN oc_order o 
ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (op.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' 
AND p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = 0 
GROUP BY op.product_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong, to insert multiple records you should do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable ( Col1, Col2, Col3 )
SELECT Val1, Val2, Val3 FROM SomeOtherTable
```